# fancybox iframe not working with Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: fancybox

I am using a fancybox version 1.3.4 to open another page in iframe. It is working fine in IE but not in Mozilla or Chrome. It is just opening another page without creating any overlay. Is the compatibility issue ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: There is not any (known) compatibility issue. If you have a link, we could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I've no answer but I stumbled on a-not-working-fancybox.. To JFK: and concerning an url: going back to base is more then often a good starting point :) so at the fancybox-homepage the iframe-example is not fully functional and more: I've downloaded the fancybox plugin and also there de iframe link (and ajax-example) is not really functional.. (btw I'm using FF7).. Greetings